# How to access and then compare the values of individual cells in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df and df1 both have 2 columns one with an object and another with a numerical value. If the objects in certain cells are the same I will add the two numbers together and print them. I tried this but I am getting a syntax error on the first line.

```
if(df.at[0,'obj'] == df1.at[0,'obj'])
  print((df.at[0,'num'] + df1.at[0,'num']))
```

The data frames are

```
import pandas as pd
dict0 = {"obj" : ["AB", "BC", "CD", "AF", "GD"],
        "num" : [20, 15, 10, 12, 8]
       }
dict1 = {"obj" : ["AB", "BD", "CZ", "AF", "GD"],
        "num" : [12, 33, 15, 7, 11]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(dict0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
df  =  df.set_index('obj')
df1  =  df1.set_index('obj')
(df + df1).dropna()
```

---

---

OR with a single shot without saving into df's:

```
(df.set_index('obj') + df1.set_index('obj')).dropna()
```